# How can I set a dynamic class on the body tag that is equal to params[:controller]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm writing this in HAML. I run: = params[:controller] in the body and it reveals the current url controller. I want to set that as a class in the body tag in haml.

Currently I'm doing:

```
 %body{:class => '#{params[:controller]}'}
```

I know that's wrong I just can't find a solution. It's probably really simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things wrong with your code:

1) String interpolation (the `#{}`) only works when the string is double-quoted, not single-quoted.

2) String interpolation isn't necessary here - you can just do `%body{:class => params[:controller]}`, because `params[:controller]` is already a string.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad practice to trust the params, so instead use `controller.controller_name` to get the name of the current controller:

```
%body{:class => controller.controller_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `%body` in your HAML produces a page with *two* `<body>` tags. That's too weird for me, so I do this:

```
:javascript
  $('body').addClass("#{@body_css}");
```

Answer (score -1):

According to the documentation:

> Brackets represent a Ruby hash that is used for specifying the
>   attributes of an element. It is literally evaluated as a Ruby hash, so
>   logic will work in it and local variables may be used.

So you can just do in your view:

```
%body{:class => controller_name} #since it's a string and you need not #{} to evaluate
```